Look up partial text through a table does not return value
I have a ticketing system where users insert a specific code in the description based on which we can categorize the department they affect. In essence i want to search for specific text through the description and look it up from a mapping of codes : departments
The codes are indicatively :
[C1] : Mobile C1
[TFS] : Fixed Stuck
I have set this mapping on another sheet.
Ι am using the following formula
IF(SEARCH("[C1]";D40;1);VLOOKUP("[C1]";Sheet3!A:B;2;FALSE);IF(SEARCH("[TFS]";D40;1);VLOOKUP("[TFS]";Sheet3!A:B;2;FALSE)))
but i get #Value on everything added after C1. If I remove the C1 search, then I get the expected result.
I have also tried countif("*"TFS"*") but i get the same result
This is the table i am using to map the information


VLOOKUP() will fail. Use XLOOKUP() with wild card matching option.

The reason of it is that, if SEARCH is unsuccessed it's returning a #VALUE error. Test it for error and place an appropriate value for it.

I will need further information on testing it for error. The formula does not have error. If i remove the [C1] part, i get results on the TFS. combined together, i get #value

Use XLOOKUP() with wild card match mode. Adjust ranges for your case.
=XLOOKUP("*[C1]*",A:A,B:B,,2)



same issue =>
=IF(SEARCH("[C1]";D40;1);XLOOKUP("[C1]";Sheet3!A:A;Sheet3!B:B;;2);IF(SEARCH("[TFS]";D40;1);XLOOKUP("[TFS]";Sheet3!A:A;Sheet3!B:B;;2)))
the values on C1 are ok. the values on TFS return #VALUE!
it seems that for some reason, excel does not interpret correctly the second IF but i cannot understand the reason why

@AkisAthanassiadis Use asterisk * like "*[C1]*".

same issue using asterisk

Can you please show screenshot if your data setup? This must work.
